# Understanding the hyperparameters C and epsilon of support vector regression

Tags: machine-learning

According to the  [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137097/understanding-support-vector-regression-svr),

> a low value of `C` means that we are okay with having outliers, so the margin will be thinned and more outliers will be produced. A high value of `C` indicates that we care a lot about not having slack, so the margin will be made bigger to accommodate these outliers at the expense of representing the overall data less well.

Doesn't that mean by varying `C`, even `epsilon` is varied? Since `epsilon` decides the width of the tube around the hyperplane. If yes, then what is the need and role `epsilon` in a SVR model?